# How can I scrape Yahoo Finance by parsing through a text file containing a list of tickers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, finance

I have a text file containing a list of company tickers.

My intention is to be able to scrape Yahoo Finance to get financial data for each of these tickers.

I do not know how to tell Python to go over each individual line in my text file, assign it to a variable and then scrape that particular Yahoo Finance page and retrieve its data and store it, repeating the process for how many tickers are contained in the text file.

I found some code online to be able to scrape data from Yahoo Finance. 
Then I tried to add a for loop so that each ticker is added to a symbol variable (see code).

```
def scrape_table(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    table = tree.xpath('//table')
    assert len(table) == 1

    df = pd.read_html(lxml.etree.tostring(table[0], method='html'))[0]

    df = df.set_index(0)
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.transpose()
    df = df.replace('-', '0')

    # The first column should be a date
    df[df.columns[0]] = pd.to_datetime(df[df.columns[0]])
    cols = list(df.columns)
    cols[0] = 'Date'
    df = df.set_axis(cols, axis='columns', inplace=False)

    numeric_columns = list(df.columns)[1::]
    df[numeric_columns] = df[numeric_columns].astype(np.float64)

    return df

symbol = []

tf = open("SMI_tickers.txt")
for line in tf.readlines():
   symbol.append(print(line))

balance_sheet_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + 
'/balance-sheet?p=' + symbol

df_balance_sheet = scrape_table(balance_sheet_url)
df_balance_sheet
```

The error message I got was

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

My end goal is to be able to import financial data for each of these companies so that I can perform some calculations on each stock.

Comment: `symbol` is a list, so you cannot use it in a string using `+`

Comment: Symbol is a list of strings. You need to iterate through the list because your function accepts individual strings. Basically you have to do one url at a time.

Comment: @Derlin it will append None to the list

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to pass a list instead of a string. You need to iterate through all the symbols in your file, which you can do as follows. This code will append the results of the scraping function (which I have not tested) to a list balance_sheets.

```
balance_sheets=[]
tf = open("SMI_tickers.txt")
for line in tf.readlines():
    symbol.append(line)
    balance_sheet_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + line + '/balance-sheet?p=' + line
    balance_sheets.append(scrape_table(balance_sheet_url))
```

Comment: So is there no way to do one command and ending up with a list of results for all tickers? I got a large error message when I tried the above code

Comment: What error did you get? Does the scrape_table function work for a single url?

Comment: It was too long to paste. It included dimensionality reduction errors. I'm assuming it was because it tried to process lots of data at once maybe

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your SMI_tickers.txt has a list of ticker symbols with one symbol per line. The erros comes when you build your url, you try to concatenate symbol, which is a list, not a string.

Change your code to below.

```
tf = open("SMI_tickers.txt")
for line in tf.readlines():
  symbol.append(line)
for symb in symbol:
    balance_sheet_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symb + 
          '/balance-sheet?p=' + symb

    df_balance_sheet = scrape_table(balance_sheet_url)
    df_balance_sheet
```

You don't actually need to read the symbols into a list, you could just use the symbol once you get it from the file without the list.

```
tf = open("SMI_tickers.txt")
for line in tf.readlines():
    balance_sheet_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + line+ 
          '/balance-sheet?p=' + line

    df_balance_sheet = scrape_table(balance_sheet_url)
    df_balance_sheet
```

In both cases df_balance_sheet will be your pandas datafram.

Answer (score 0):

For scraping balance sheet info, amongst anything else you might like, check out the yahoo_fin package http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/
Makes things a wee bit easier

```
import pandas as pd
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_balance_sheet

stock_list = ["AAPL", "IBM", "AMZN"]

all_data = {ticker: get_balance_sheet(ticker)
                 for ticker in stock_list}

aapl = pd.DataFrame(all_data['AAPL'])
aapl = aapl.set_index('Period Ending')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped!

Comment: I have produced a data frame with the balance sheet data. My intention is to be able to select a few rows and then divide the values from a particular row by the corresponding values in another row. What's an easy way to do this in a Pandas dataframe

Comment: When doing operations on a dataframe like divisions, it helps to have the things we're operating on be columns. To do this we can easily transpose the dataframe with df.transpose()

Comment: The code: https://github.com/aronnyberg/stackoverflow/blob/master/for%20owenzammit

Comment: Is it possible to add a for loop to this bit of code:                                   
 ``all_data = {ticker: get_balance_sheet(ticker)
                 for ticker in stock_list}
So that I don't have to write each ticker symbol manual into this bit of code?
aapl = pd.DataFrame(all_data['AAPL'])